# How to automatically generate a field based on the choice of a previous field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model and some serializers in Django Rest Framework.  I would like to have choices for the "service_interval" field and then based on what they choose it generates the date correctly in the database.  How would I do this?

Here's my code.

```
class Snippet(VIPSnippet):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    service_interval_choices = [
        (3, '3 Months'),
        (6 , '6 Months'),
        (9, '9 Months'),
        (12, '1 Year'),
    ]
    service_interval = models.IntegerField(choices=service_interval_choices)
    next_service = models.DateTimeField()
```

Serializers

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-highlight', format='html')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ['url', 'service_interval']
        next_service = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(3*365/12)
```

When I do it this way I get the following error

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_snippet.next_service
```

I plan to replace the '3' in datetime.timedelta(3*365/12) with service_interval or whatever variable I would need so that it generates the date however may months in the future as needed.

Comment: I think you should include next_service in fields and then define self.fields['next_service'] = ...

Comment: I get ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str``` when I try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by overriding [the serializer's `validate`-method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation):

```py
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-highlight', format='html')
    
    def validate(self, data):
        data["next_service"] = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(data["service_interval"]*365/12)
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = [
            'url',
            'service_interval',
            'next_service',
            # also you need to include the fields defined on the serializer here:
            'owner',
            'highlight',
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had to change a couple of things and had left those fields on from earlier fields that I had taken out.  I have it working now though!  Thank you!